# Add type for action.payload in extraReducers - Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reduce, redux-toolkit, payload

I'm trying to implement authentication using Redux Toolkit and TypeScript. Firstly I create signUp using createAsyncThunk like this.

```
const signUp = createAsyncThunk<
    string | null,
    {
        name: string;
        email: string;
        password: string;
        avatar: string;
    }
>(
    "user/signup",
    async ({ name, email, password, avatar }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            };

            await axios.post(
                `${backendURL}/api/user/register`,
                { name, email, password, avatar },
                config
            );

            return null;
        } catch (error: any) {
            if (error.response && error.response.data.message) {
                return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
            } else {
                return rejectWithValue(error.message);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

And then the reducer

```
const initialState: {
    userToken: string | null;
    loading: boolean;
    userInfo: { userId: string; email: string } | null;
    error: string | null;
    success: boolean;
} = {
    userToken,
    loading: false,
    userInfo: null,
    error: null,
    success: false,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "authen",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        logout: (state) => {
            localStorage.removeItem("userToken");
            state.loading = false;
            state.userInfo = null;
            state.userToken = null;
            state.error = null;
        },
        setCredentials: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.userInfo = payload;
        },
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(signUp.pending, (state) => {
                state.loading = true;
                state.error = null;
            })
            .addCase(signUp.fulfilled, (state) => {
                state.loading = false;
                state.success = true;
            })
            .addCase(signUp.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.loading = false;
                state.error = action.payload;
            })          
    },
});
```

And because I don't specify any type for action so an error message showing when Im trying to assign action.payload to state.userInfo, but I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

I've searching around but found no answer

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to provide that type - it will be inferred from the `createAsyncThunk` instance you pass in there - in the case of `signUp` to `string | null`.

Maybe you didn't type that correctly for `signIn`?

Comment: I wrote it as signIn, but the IDE still can't infer the type of action.payload. In "state.error = action.payload" it show the message say that "Type unknown is not assignable to type string| null"

Comment: Your signIn thunk above is typed to return `void` in the fulfilled case. Also, for the error case: that error will be `unknown` until you  do a type assertion or use a type guard function in your reducer.  That's just analog to a `catch` block where the error will always be `unknown` as well.